# Writing function to replace often used case pattern

Tags: bash, shell, switch-statement

I am trying to do something like:

```
fn()
{
    "reusedPattern")
        #do stuff
        ;;
}
```

and call it within a select case

```
select stuff in ${something[@]}
do
    case $stuff in
       "pattern1")
            #do stuff
            ;;
     ...
       fn
     ...
       *) echo invalid input ;;
done
```

When executing script, bash doesn't like the function (gives me error regarding the ")" and the ";;").

What would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can only have complete commands, not a fragment of a `case` statement.

What you can do is to define the `#do stuff` part in a function, and call it from the `case` command:

```
reusedPatternCommands()
{
    #do stuff
    echo "reusedPattern"
}

select stuff in ${something[@]}
do
    case $stuff in
       "pattern1")
            #do stuff
            ;;
     ...
       "reusedPattern")
            reusedPatternCommands
     ...
       *) echo invalid input ;;
done
```

Comment: Is there another type of package that can do what I'm wanting? I'll accept that functions can't do _exactly_ what i'm wanting, but anything else?

Comment: You can create a parser that process your script searching for that kind of function, and output an executable shell script with that code inlined.